# PDF editor with regular expressions for bookmarks?

Tags: software-rec, pdf

Are there any Unix-based PDF editors with automatic bookmark creation?

Comment: What do you mean by “automatic bookmark creation”? Do you mean that in addition to any existing bookmark, they should create bookmarks based on the printed text in the file?

Comment: It should examine the contents of the PDF, and create bookmarks based on the font and text. There may or may not be bookmarks beforehand. [Example](http://www.nitropdf.com/help/automate_pdf_bookmark_creation.htm)